# What I'm missing here? IsSuccessStatusCode not valid

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

In my code I'm trying to communicate with a php webservice.  In my Xamarin code in Csharp IsSuccessStatusCode it's invalid "'string' does not contain a definition for "isSuccessStatusCode'....  All codes i seen in the net includes this but i don't know it's not working for me.

```
private async void GetDataAsync()
{
    //nota: para que await funcione hay que escribir en la rutina al lado de private async
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://192.168.1.33:82/usuarios_xamarin/Usuarios.php");


    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Posts>>(content);
    }
    //pertenece al nugget newtonsoft.json
    //si no esta instalado hay que instalarlo en los nuggets

    //var posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Posts>>(response);


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

response is a string and string doesnt have a method IsSuccessStatusCode. If you use `GetAsync` instead of `GetStringAsync`, then you can use the property (`IsSuccessStatusCode`) of `response`.

[Documentation on HttpClient.GetAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's right. `string` does not have a property called IsSuccessStatusCode. [HttpResponseMessage does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.issuccessstatuscode?view=netcore-3.1).

You are calling the endpoint and converting the response directly to `string`. If you wanted to check the status code of the response, you want to do this in two parts:

```cs
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://192.168.1.33:82/usuarios_xamarin/Usuarios.php");
if (response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode) 
{
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```